# Two Images - Display other image if image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, image, switch-statement

I am trying to find a way to switch an image on click.

I have two images.

I have one page, on this page I have one of the images displayed.

If I click on the image, I would like the other image to be loaded in its place.

I know a bit about html and css, and a bit less about php. I am assuming the correct way to go about this would be the use of javascript. Unfortunately, I know nothing about this.

Here is my code so far, what I want to do, is have .../page-2.jpg loaded when this image is clicked.

```
$pageContent = '
<h2>Promotions</h2>
<div class="promo-img">
<img src="'.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg" alt="Page 1" name="Page 1" width="100%" height="150%" id="page1" style="background: #FFF; display:block;" />
</div>
';
```

Any input here would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

@Dennis

Where am I going wrong with this?

```
$pageContent = '
<h2>Promotions</h2>
<div class="promo-img"><img id="promoImage" src="'.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg" alt="Page 1" width="100%" height="150%" style="background: #FFF; display:block;" 
onClick="document.getElementById(\'promoImage\').onclick = function() {
if(this.src == \''.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg\'){
    this.src = \''.$docPath.'/page-2.jpg\';
} else {
    this.src = \''.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg\';
}
};" /></div>
';
```

Okay, This does not seem to have an onclick effect?

```
$pageContent = '
<h2>Promotions</h2>
<div class="promo-img"><img id="promoImage" src="'.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg" alt="Page 1" width="100%" height="150%" style="background: #FFF;" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById(\'promoImage\').onclick = function() {
if(this.src == \''.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg\'){
    this.src = \''.$docPath.'/page-2.jpg\';
} else {
    this.src = \''.$docPath.'/page-1.jpg\';
}
};
</script>
';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="first.jpg">
```

Javascript: (click to switch)

```
document.getElementById("image").onclick = function() {
    if(this.src == "first.jpg"){
        this.src = "second.jpg";
    } else {
        this.src = "first.jpg";
    }
};
```

Javascript: (hover to switch)

```
document.getElementById("image").onmouseover = function() {
    this.src = "second.jpg";
};
document.getElementById("image").onmouseout = function() {
    this.src = "first.jpg";
};
```

These are the simplest techniques.  There are "better" solutions using jQuery or CSS that separate code from the HTML.

Comment: thank you for the input! Being a really new to javascript though, how would I link the two together? Please take a look at my Post, I edited it to reflect how I assume it should work?

Comment: Don't use the inline onclick attribute.  Put the code in a `<script>...</script>` block.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I updated my post again, please take a look. This seems to be the correct way, but when I hover my mouse over the image, or click on it, it produces no effect.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!! Thank you so much! Just one last thing though, is it possible to have the cursor change to the link cursor when I hover over the image? It is quite confusing, as you wouldnt know to click unless told to do so.

Comment: @mVChr Thanks, solved my original problem, but Dennis has given me a much better solution :)

Comment: @Dennis Now that stands out! Absolutely perfect, thank you! I am making a website for my work, we work with very slow people, so your idea will really aid that problem! I have no words to explain how grateful I am, thank you!